# In linux how can I tell if I'm linking to a static or dynamic library?

Tags: c++, linux, dynamic, static

I have a static and a dynamic library with the same name: libclsocket.a and libclsocket.so When I specify what library I want to link to i simply enter -lclsocket as the library. My program complies and runs perfectly fine, but what library am I using? the static library or the dynamic library? I want to give my friend my program, and I'm not sure If i need to include the libraries in the release. C++, codelite, pcLinuxOS 2010

Comment: You didn't specify the `-static` flag when building with GCC, so most likely you are linking to the shared object. As @Soo Wei Tan answered, you can use `ldd` on the binary to determine its runtime linker dependencies.

Comment: Can I specify want library should be linked statically?

Comment: you can selectively static link by passing the full name of the library. Like `gcc -o OutFile <source files> -l:libclsocket.a`. Note the `:`, it is very important. I would like to find out official documentation for this behavior, but `gcc`'s manpages don't mention this use.

Comment: @birryree you said : is very important. What else is it used for? Does gcc automatically used shared libraries? Is -l:<fullLibName.so> good practice?

Comment: if you don't put in the colon, the command doesn't work (for the thing you're trying to do). By default, how gcc links is platform dependent. gcc passes on options to an underlying linker (generally GNU ld on Linux systems, but could be something else on other platforms, like link.exe on Windows, and Sun ld on Solaris), and the linker does its work. By default on Linux/Windows, the underlying linker will attempt dynamic linking, so you don't have to do full-name linking, if you wanted to link to the shared object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try running `ldd` on the executable and seeing if the accompanying .so is being detected as required in the list of dependencies.

ldd man page is [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ldd).

Comment: It is linking to the shared libraries. So how would I link to a static lib? I'm also assuming it defaults to shared libraries.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the `-static` flag, all components will be made static. And `-l` may include shared libraries. So specifying the static library filename (e.g. with `/usr/lib/libfoo.a` for example, no `-l` prepended), should get you the desired effect.