# MSVC command-line option to remove debug information

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I have the following simple C++ program in a file called "hw.cpp":

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling with gcc 9.3.0 (Ubuntu), gives the following results:

- gcc -g0 hw.cpp -o hw.out (disable debug info) => size is 17k (same if `-g0` is removed)
- gcc -g3 hw.cpp -o hw.out (maximum debug info) => size is 44k

But the default compile for MSVC (cl version 19.26.28806) outputs a much bigger file:

- cl hw.cpp /link /out:hw.exe => size is 101k

Why is the MSVC version so big? Is this related to debug information and how do is debug information disabled? The [cl.exe compiler options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-options-listed-by-category?view=vs-2019) don't have an obvious equivalent for the gcc `-gN` options.

Comment: It's a **linker** option (`/DEBUG:NONE`). See [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59800111/10871073). Add the switch immediately after `/link`. [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/link-pass-options-to-linker?view=vs-2019).

Comment: @AdrianMole: Thanks, but the command `cl hw.cpp /link /DEBUG:NONE /out:hw.exe` made no difference (size still 101k). Is the syntax right?

Comment: The syntax looks OK. I guess MSVC is adding all sorts of run-time library stuff in the executable.

Comment: @AlainD Is `gcc` linking by default to the static or shared/dynamic CRT in your environment?

Comment: @dxiv: Umm, how do I check this?...Sorry, Linux novice! New installation of Ubuntu 20.04, then ran commands like `sudo apt install build-essential gcc g++ (etc)`. Haven't configured anythign specific with gcc.

Comment: @AlainD And I am not really familiar with your environment, sorry, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4281367) suggests `ldd`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the `hw.exe` sizes I am seeing for the combinations of static/dynamic linking of the C runtime vs. debug/release builds for a default 32b compile of your `hw.cpp` with VC++ 2019.

```
                   debug                 release
static      (cl /MTd)  279,040      (cl /MT)  101,888
dynamic     (cl /MDd)   10,240      (cl /MD)    8,192
```

The 32b release build `cl /MD hw.cpp` dynamically linked to VCRUNTIME140.DLL runtime has 8k. The big jump in size with `/MT` comes from statically linking the core C support, stream library etc.

Comment: Am able confirm all those sizes using the `/MTx` and `/MDx` options using VS 2019 Community on Windows 10 (although my static-linked debug version was 278,528 bytes). Thanks!